# Possible to make a SQL query to count for every hour of a day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL Table which stores some data and a date (e.g. yyyymmdd) and a time (e.g. hhmmss).
Now I need to select a count of the number of entries for every hour of the day.

- First count of entries will be: 000000 til 005959
- Second will be: 010000 til 015959

Is it possible to make this with a single select and then have an array of 24 count results? Otherwise I will need to create 24 selects to get all the data I want.

Comment: Mysql or sql-server  ?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: This is where you should use a tally or numbers table as the main table in your query.

Comment: mysql, did not try anything because I dont know how to do it. I would create 24 individual querys, but I know that this is not a good solution.

Comment: select hour (time_column), count (*)
    from table
    group by hour(time_column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by function. Another option is to create fields for hour, minutes and seconds. It will duplicate data, but there is no problem.

```
CREATE TABLE test(id int, date varchar(8), time varchar(6));

INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'20160616','015959');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'20160616','015959');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,'20160616','025959');

  SELECT count(substr(time,1,2)), test.date
    FROM test
GROUP BY date, substr(time,1,2);
```

Output:

```
count(substr(time,1,2)), date
'2', '20160616'
'1', '20160616'
```

If you have a `TIME` column, just use:

```
  SELECT count(hour(time)), test.date
    FROM test
GROUP BY date, hour(time);
```

If you don't need to have this count by `date`, just remove from `select` and `group by` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the HOUR function.  I don't use MYSQL, but it looks like it has this feature.  Might check the syntax on it.

```
SELECT HOUR(TheTimeField), COUNT(*)
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY HOUR(TheTimeField)
ORDER BY HOUR(TheTimeField)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select hour (time_column), count (*)
from table
group by hour(time_column)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour